# Closed Sets are Measurable Proof in Stein/Shakarchi Text

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Had a question about the proof laid out in Stein/Shakarchi's text that closed sets are measurable. Im hoping someone can explain the part in bold below, which is the only thing that's bugging me. They first assume F to be compact and show this is equivalent to it being closed, so take F to be compact:

Suppose $F$ is compact, which implies we can find a $O$ such that $F_*\subset O$ and $m_*(O)\leq m_*(F)+\epsilon$.

Since $F$ is closed, then $O\backslash F$ is open and we write it as a countable union of almost disjoint cubes $\implies O\backslash F = \bigcup_i Q_i$

Fix an $N$. The finite union $K=\bigcup_i^{N}Qi$ is compact, which means that $d(K,F)>0$

This implies that $m_*(O)\geq m_*(F)+m_*(K)= m_*(F)+\sum_i^{N}m_*(Q_i)$

Which works out to be equivalent to $\sum_i^{N}m_*(Q_i)\leq m_*(O)-m_*(F)\leq \epsilon$

**Here's where i get lost:
The authors then claim that "this holds as N goes to infinity"...Why?**

Which gives us $m_*(O\backslash F)\leq \sum_i^{\infty}m_*(Q_i)\leq m_*(O)-m_*(F)\leq \epsilon$

Comment: In general if $a_n$ converges to $L$ and $a_n<c$ $\forall$ $n$ then $L\leq c$.

Comment: For those interested in the source, the book's title is "Real analysis: measure theory, integration and Hilbert spaces" by Stein and Shakarchi. The claim appears in page 17, Property 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is independent of $N$, that is, it holds for all $N$. Since $m_*$ is non negative, this implies that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty m_*(Q_i)=\sup_N\sum_{i=1}^Nm_*(Q_i)\le\epsilon.
$$